# Best Android phone for £150 or less?

Tags: android, smartphones

I currently have a Moto G (1st Gen) and have been very happy with it. I like its durability and unadulterated version of Android. My only gripes are the lack of storage (8GB) and the weak camera (5MP). I use my phone for calls, browsing the web and photos of my children. I don't play very graphics-heavy games on it.

Grateful for your thoughts, thanks.

**Edit:** I should probably say, although it might be apparent, I want a contract-free phone.

Comment: Have a look at the Nokia 3.

Comment: Used phones give you more for less.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the **Wileyfox Swift 2 Plus**, available at Amazon for [£149.99 + Free shipping](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B01MFEOBJY/)

Like Motorola's Moto G series, the Swift 2 has a relatively unadulterated Android experience. In this case, you have the option of sticking with the CyanogenMod 13, which it ships with, upgrading to their official ROM, currently at 7.1.2, or installing LineageOS.

Storage is 32 GB, which should be sufficient for most, especially if microSD expansion and cloud storage are taken advantage of. RAM is similarly generous, with 3 GB, meaning multitasking and cache won't be a problem.

The camera sensor is a decent 16 MP, though the dynamic range is unspectacular. The aperture (f/2.0) is larger than most phones at this price, though as can be expected, there is no Optical Image Stabilization. Battery life is mediocre at best, though some users report [5 to 7 hours SoT](https://www.reddit.com/r/wileyfox/comments/636di8/swift_2_battery_life_is_it_defective_or_have_i/dfs3e5r/).

The display is a undistinguished 720p LCD. It has most of the usual extras, such as NFC, USB-C and Speed Charging. The fingerprint sensor is on the back of the phone – though normally handy, it may be less convenient if you usually leave it lying on a table, – and unfortunately the second SIM slot only supports 2G and is obstructed if you choose to install a microSD card for storage.

Overall, the Wileyfox Swift 2 Plus is a solid and stylish phone for the sub-£200 segment, and I doubt you'll go wrong with it.

[Techradar review](http://www.techradar.com/reviews/wileyfox-swift-2-plus-review)

Answer (score 1):

A tad over budget at $165, but you might find it cheaper elsewhere.

I am on my fourth [Ulefone](http://ulefone.com/) and have been happy with them all. I bought my first because it was the first 64-bit smartphone & have continued to upgrade ever since.

Some are sub £150, but I am recommending the [Ulefoen Power](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Smartphone-1080pixel-MTK6750T-Octa-Core-Fingerprint-Black/dp/B07255WNYG/) :

> Operating system : Android 7.0 CPU: MTK6750T, Octa-Core 1.5GHz
>   Storage: 4GB RAM +64GB ROM with Max. Expansion Supported 256GB
>   Memory  Card: TF Card
>   SIM : Dual sim dual standby, Nano SIM +Nano SIM / TF
>   WiFi : 2.4/5GHz  802.11a/b/g/n.
>   Size: 5.5 inch
>   Resolution: FHD  1920*1080 pixels
>   Glass : Corning® Gorilla® 3
>   Camera: Rear camera 13.0MP+ Front camera 8.0MP with Flash Capacity
>   (mAh): 6050mAh(Lithium-ion Polymer Battery) 
>   Charge: 9V/2A Quick charge,
>   Standby Time: 1160 Hours
>   Touch ID: Front Fingerprint Scanner
>   Bluetooth: Bluetooth 4.0
>   Positioning: Gyro Sensor GPS/Glonass, Gravity Sensor, E-Compass, Touch Sensor, OTG，LED notification
>   Functions: FM,Miracast,hotknot

Like you, I don't play very graphics-heavy games, but with octo-core you certainly could.

It only has 4gB, which you might not like, but a cheap SD card will fix that. I install everything on SD and have not seen a performance hit.

The 13MP and 8MP cameras should please you; it is rare to see such a good front camera.

The main point for me is that stonking 6050 mAH battery, which means that I charge it every 4 days or so (although they claim Standby Time: 1160 Hours).

I showed a few previous Ulefones to chaps at the office, who bought one and have been happy with them.